# Light source changing in XTK

Tags: xtk

Can I change scene light source (location or brightness)? My scene by XTK is too dark: 
 https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84856120/xtkskull.png
I want like by Paraview
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84856120/paraviewskull.png
**I use .stl file and 'ffffff' color**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and did not really solved it but found a work around.
I had this kind of rendering:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13268696/Ugly.png

You can see some of STL files are OK, but one is ugly. It looks like there is no shading, only a big mass. This STL has been generated using blender, and normals seemed to be OK in blender, oriented toward exterior. This phenomenom is not constant, I mean that sometimes STLs from blender are ok. For exemple, the blue one has been generated exclusively by blender.
So, I had opened it using paraview, and "save as" and generated a new STL file.
Now, here is the result:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13268696/OK.png

I don't really know what happened during blender export and paraview export, but it is related to STL generation, and not xtk display. Maybe STL import module from xtk? Incorrect interpretation ?

Hope this helps.

Laurent.

Comment: I think it is just a problem of missing normals for the one surface. Paraview re-calculates the normals. And in Stas's case, the normals need to be inverted.